# Add a turtle's variable value to another turtle's variable value

Tags: netlogo

I am struggling with trying to write this command. 
Basically, what I want to do is this:
I have a collectors [own carryingcapacity], bins [own waste in bins] and warehouses [own waste_in_warehouse] as turtles. 
The collectors have a maximum carrying capacity value.
I want to make the collectors check if they have carrying capacity when they find a bin, if trash in bin <= collectors max capacity, the collectors will collect, if not they'll ignore the bin.

I came up with something like this:

```
ask collectors 
[
  if any? bins with [distance myself <= 1] 
   [set carryingcapacity (carryingcapacity + (bins_holding_capacity of myself))]
]
```

Second command:

I want to make the collectors take the trash they collected to the warehouse. But this variable's value might change from one collector to another, and might vary with the quantity of bins they checked. 
I want the warehouse to sum the value that it already had it on the previous days with the new daily values. 
I came up with something like this as a line of command:

```
ask warehouses 
[
  if any? collectors with [distance myself <= 1] 
    [set waste_in_warehouse ( waste_in_warehouse + (carryingcapacity of myself))]
```

Thank you in advance.

Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, your code for command #1 is doing the following:

1. ask collector agents
2. See if there are any bins close to a collector (but you *didn't* ask for this group)
3. increment the collector's `carryingcapacity` by `(bins_holding_capacity) of myself` (you can't use `myself` like this, because you *aren't in a nested ask*)

Step 3's logic also seems wrong, since this would be changing the collector's capacity each time, as opposed to checking if it is full.

It should be noted that by using `any?`, **you are not also commanding that group of agents**. `any?` only returns `true` or `false`, corresponding to whether there were agents that met the criteria or not. You need to use a second `ask` to command these agents.

Based on what you said, you'll need to do something like this:

```
ask collectors 
[
  ask bins with [distance myself <= 1] ;;myself refers to the collector asking
  [
    ifelse (waste_in_bin + [waste_in_collector] of myself) > [carryingcapacity] of myself
      [;;add the waste to the collector] 
      [;;stop asking bins, collector is full] 
  ]
]
```

These same steps should help with your second question, too.

Comment: Thank you Ryan, I have had to make some adjustments because the ifelse command asks for two command blocks. I am still working on the code, but I really appreciate you taking your time to help me.